# Different docker image being created from command line and JetBrains WebStorm

Tags: docker, dockerfile, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am creating a docker image. When I create it from WebStorm it creates a different image ( that doesn't run most importantly ) than when I create it with `docker build`.

Is this something that WebStorm does that I am unaware of given both methods are using the exact same files and Dockerfile yet are creating different images?

```
FROM cm2network/steamcmd:root

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y curl \
    && apt install -y nodejs -y npm

WORKDIR /home/steam/steamcmd
VOLUME /home/steam/steamcmd

COPY . .

RUN npm install

USER steam

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "./src/index.js"]
```

The error says that the `vdf` package ( first one required ) isn't installed.

Log from terminal when running `docker build -t <tag> .`

```
[+] Building 12.1s (10/10) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 310B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/cm2network/steamcmd:root                                                0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/cm2network/steamcmd:root                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 7.20kB                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] RUN apt update     && apt install -y curl     && apt install -y nodejs -y npm                     0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] WORKDIR /home/steam/steamcmd                                                                      0.0s
 => [4/5] COPY . .                                                                                                 0.1s
 => [5/5] RUN npm install                                                                                          9.8s
 => exporting to image                                                                                             2.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                            2.1s
 => => writing image sha256:b1c36641fc4d49cff4d38092879d556c6257a96cc55b4401827cac7c5f72c5c9                       0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/steamcmd-terminal                                                               0.0s
```

Log from WebStorm when using the native docker config:

```
Deploying 'steamcmd-webstorm Dockerfile: Dockerfile'…
Building image…
Preparing build context archive…
[==================================================>]50/50 files
Done

Sending build context to Docker daemon…
[==================================================>] 18.14kB
Done

Step 1/9 : FROM cm2network/steamcmd:root
 ---> d490902b909c
Step 2/9 : RUN apt update     && apt install -y curl     && apt install -y nodejs -y npm
 ---> Running in 56188b34650b

<Taken out the entire logs here as it's massive but nothing exciting seems to be going on here. Just installing Node and npm>

Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /home/steam/steamcmd
 ---> Running in 5c9c276586ce
Removing intermediate container 5c9c276586ce
 ---> c93a98ea80fe
Step 4/9 : VOLUME /home/steam/steamcmd
 ---> Running in e608a8c467f4
Removing intermediate container e608a8c467f4
 ---> 03f450c267b2
Step 5/9 : COPY . .
 ---> bcd9ce25e8a5
Step 6/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 16a46251730b

added 93 packages, and audited 94 packages in 8s

38 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Removing intermediate container 16a46251730b
 ---> 49bac07990ea
Step 7/9 : USER steam
 ---> Running in a50475541075
Removing intermediate container a50475541075
 ---> 9f8b28506b7f
Step 8/9 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 17e53097f7b4
Removing intermediate container 17e53097f7b4
 ---> 11788721f0c2
Step 9/9 : CMD ["node", "./src/index.js"]
 ---> Running in 99d37cb33066
Removing intermediate container 99d37cb33066
 ---> 95ce7c9c21b7

Successfully built 95ce7c9c21b7
Successfully tagged steamcmd-webstorm:latest
'steamcmd-webstorm Dockerfile: Dockerfile' has been deployed successfully.
```

Comment: Can you share the whole log (when building the docker image with WebStorm)?

Comment: Edited message to include logs